# Laravel $this->withoutExceptionHandling(); Not Working

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm running Laravel 5.8 and this function isn't working for my tests. I've put it in the individual tests as the laracast video shows and i've also put it in the setup method. I'm still getting `Failed asserting that 500 matches expected 201` type errors without a stacktrace. Anybody know why this could be?

PHPUnit 7.5.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors

```
/** @test */
public function test_name(){
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    $response = $this->post("path/url/");
    $this->assertEquals(201, $response->getStatusCode());
}
```

Comment: Please can you show the code you have. Also, what version of Laravel and PHPUnit are you using?

Comment: made the requested edits

Comment: Sorry could you also show the code you have for that route? Also, have you updated your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` in any way?

Comment: I did not update the Handler.php. The issue i'm having is with tests and laravel's testing framework not the code in the route...although I understand it's returning a 500 in the route code.